# Parked domain redirect to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domain:

- `maindomain.com`
- `parkeddomain.com`

Before having the `parkeddomain.com` domain, my `.htaccess` was:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Now that I have the new domain, I want to redirect the visits in a subfolder: `/park/`
So basically, if the following URI would display the exact same page:

- `http://www.maindomain.com/park/`
- `http://www.parkeddomain.com/`

My attempt to make a `.htaccess` rule was:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parkeddomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /park/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

But for a strange reason, the `[L]` clause of the park `RewriteRule` generate an internal `500 error`, and I don't have access to the log file :(

Any solution ?
thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 500 error most likely because your rule enters into a rewrite loop. Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parkeddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/park/$1 [R=302,L]
```

1. It is 302 temporal redirect (because your domain is parked and one day you may decide to actually start using it). But if you really want to can make it 301 Permanent redirect
2. The rule will work if user come via parkeddomain.com (e.g. `http://www.parkeddomain.com/hello`).

If you **do not want redirect** (so URL in a browser still shows `http://www.parkeddomain.com/hello` instead of `http://www.maindomain.com/park/hello`), use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parkeddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/park/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /park/$1 [L]
```

---

**UPDATE**
This rule will allow to rewrite even this kind of URLs: `parkeddomain.com/park/index.php` -> `/park/park/index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parkeddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/park/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /park/$1 [L]
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** Because it uses `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` it **may** not work on your hosting (this is used to detect rewrite loop so the rule is only rewritten once).

Comment: Exact, the last one seem to be the one I need; I want the visitor thinking his on 2 different domains, with no subfolder.. no redirect. Right now the redirect work for file inside the park/ folder, but I also have files in /park/park/ ( yes I know, don't ask ...), and they return a 500 error :-\

Comment: @FMaz008 I have added new rule to my answer which should allow you to rewrite even such scenario. But please note -- it **may** not work on your hosting (old Apache/mod_rewrite version maybe) -- it works fine on my 2.2.17.

Comment: Looks like no challenge are too hard for you when it come to rewrite rules ;). That's what I needed, Thanks ! :)